# What is the difference between a "kulo" and a "moskito"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I believe they are not equivalent. *Moskito* is more broad and only one sub-family of moskitos are *Kuloj* (Culex). But I am not sure of it.

Comment: I learned the word _moskito_ - probably from one of the English dictionaries - but I was rather surprised in Europe to find that everybody was calling the mosquitos _kuloj_. Anybody that I found, if they were familiar with the term _moskito_ thought it referred to the biters in Africa that carried malaria. Keep in mind that "culex" is a genus, not a "sub family" and so is already a very broad term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vikipedio has an [explanation for this](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moskito). Basically it seems that both *kulo* and *moskito* are technically two different species of biting insect, both of which are in a family called *kuledoj*. *Moskito* is the correct name for the annoying biting one that everybody hates, but actually in practice people colloquially use the word *kulo* to refer to anything in the family of *kuledoj*.

In my personal experience I believe I hear the word *kulo* to refer these annoying insects much more frequently. It's an especially good word because it opens up the opportunity for jokes about “*la fi·kuloj*”.

Comment: The same Wiki article seems to be saying that the words are synonyms. 

"Moskito (aŭ Kulo) estas membro de la familio Kuledoj "

Aliloke en la artikolo oni indikas la diferencon (simile al kion mi diris en alia komento):

"Por la tropikaj specioj de la kuledoj oni plej ofte uzas la vorton moskito. "

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Tiu aldono estas nova kaj ŝajnas esti eraro, ĉar ĝi ne kongruas kun la restaĵo de la artikolo.

Answer (score 4):

*Kulo* is the general term for a biting fly, *moskito* are specifically those bastardly little blood-suckers everyone hates.

**kulo** 
*Malgranda insekto kies ino suĉas sangon de mamuloj k birdoj, k kies piko kaŭzas malagrablan jukadon*  
A small insect whose female sucks blood from mammals and birds, and the bite causes uncomfortable itching.

**moskito** 
*pikantaj dipteraj insektoj, precipe el la fam. de kuledoj* 
Flying biting insects, especially from the family Culicidae (Mosquito)

Comment: Hmm, nun mi dubas min mem. La supra respondo estas kiel mi cxiam uzis la vortojn kaj la difinoj sxajnas subteni tion, cxu ne? O_o

Comment: Nu, Makis - atentu ankaux ke "diptera" signifas musxeca, cxu ne? Mi rimarkas diferencon en uzo inter usono kaj euxropo.

Comment: Gxuste, sed per sercxo de tekstaro, mi ne trovis zamenhan uzon de _moskito_, sed multaj por _kulo_. Kaj tio, laux mi, signifus, ke eble la vorto _moskito_ estis kreita poste por specife signifi _mosquito_, cxu ne?

Comment: Nu - tio signifas nur ke (ial) Z preferis la vorton "kulo."

Comment: Aux eble cxar tiutempe nur _kulo_ ekzistis.... ;)

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Parenteze, cxu vi estas la Tomaso kiun mi renkontis cxe NASK?

Answer (score 1):

According to my dictionary (John C. Wells's), a *kulo* is a gnat and a *moskito* is a mosquito.